# Any alternatives to copying jars to GWT's web/WEB-INF/lib directory when using Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gwt

An Eclipse (Indigo) GWT project is not a "Dynamic Web Application," so there's no notion of a Deployment Assembly. Consequently, I can't seem to deploy a jar to a GWT web application without physically copying the jar (or making a symlink) to *project*/war/WEB-INF/lib. I hate the idea of having multiple copies of the jar, however, and links are difficult to manage under version control.

Does anybody have a way to fix this problem? Ideally, I'd be able to tell the GWT Eclipse plugin to deploy all the jars in a standard Eclipse "User Library." I'd like the plugin to continue to compile/deploy without falling back to ant.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

This is a clear system for build and deploy your project. Used in many java project as de-facto build system. I'm using it to build my GWT+Spring projects just in one click.

Also, there is excellent integration of maven in eclipse/idea/netbeans.

For building the GWT project using maven, you just have to include some libraries and plugins in yor pom.xml:

```
<properties>
     <java-version>1.6</java-version>
     <gwtVersion>2.4.0</gwtVersion>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<plugins>
    <!-- Java compiler -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>${java-version}</source>
            <target>${java-version}</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <!-- WAR packager -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <warName>myAppWar</warName>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <!-- GWT plugin -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```